# Plot the json array using jquery flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flot

```
var data =[ { label: "Foo", data: [ ["2012-09-01", 1], ["2012-10-01", -14], ["2012-11-01", 5] ] },
                { label: "Bar", data: [ ["2012-09-01", 13], ["2012-10-01", 11], ["2012-11-01", -7] ] }
    ];
    var options = {
        series: {
            lines: { show: true },
            points: { show: true }
        }
    };


<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script>
$.plot($('#placeholder'), data, options);
</script>
```

I am confused why the graph is not getting plotted with the data. Ignore my novice knowledge on flot. Can anyone give me an idea how i should be able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure flot can handle values formatted as strings? You should probably convert the strings to real dates or milliseconds...

You can use the moment.js library:

```
var data =[ { label: "Foo", data: [ [moment("2012-09-01","YYYY-MM-DD").toDate(), 1], ...
```

Comment: Instead of moment.js, I am converting it the date to time in milliseconds and used `xaxis: {mode: "time", timeformat: "%b-%Y"}`. It worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

Flot does not automatically parse dates.  If you want those to be used as-is then you should include the [categories plugin](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories).  If you actually want to treat them as dates then you should convert them to dates as Nikos suggested and then take a look at the [time plugin](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time).